# Control two windows at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, window-focus

I want control Excel with my keyboard while using the mouse on Firefox. I need to maximize Excel and I have two monitors so covering the distance to travel between them is a little annoying.

Windows 7 x64

Comment: Alt-tab is your friend.

Comment: Can I suggest using two monitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you want to do more than just use the scroll wheel in Firefox?  The scroll wheel should work to control whatever widow the mouse is hovering over.

I don't think it is possible to give the keyboard focus to one application, and mouse focus to another application.

Comment: That is the case in OSX, which is awesome. I wish there was something like that on windows.

Comment: switched to linux... works as it does on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

The term "focusing", in OS, means that the input should be received by a module, a window (called Form) in the Windows environment. By input we understand mouse and keyboard.
The main rule is: **one and only one** module can be focused.
This means that you cannot focus two or more modules and that you must have a focused module.
There is an exception tho, **listeners**, which listen to the OS's keyboard and mouse events and reports them. I humbly think that an Excel or, generally, Office add-on can create a listener and simulate the input in the window programmatically, but I have never used the API so I don't know exactly. Such an add-on wouldn't be too practical either.